# SGML Named entity for U+1e7c (Ṽ) & U+1e7d (ṽ)?

Tags: unicode, html-entities, sgml

I need to use the named entities for special character, but unable to find any thing for the two character U+1e7c (Ṽ) & U+1e7d (ṽ)?, i searched for it unable to find any where in the available lists online. kindly help.

Comment: Use this tool: https://mothereff.in/html-entities#%E1%B9%BC%0A%E1%B9%BD and enable the “allow named character references in output (incompatible with older browsers)” checkbox. This demonstrates that there are no such built-in named entities. Use a numerical variant, or [create your own as explained in Daniel’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32744893/96656).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there are named entities for those characters. You can make your own though or just use either the hex (`&#x1e7c;` and `&#x1e7d;`) or dec (`&#7804;` and `&#7805;`) references.

Example of creating your own named entities:

```
<!ENTITY Vtilde "&#x1e7c;">
<!ENTITY vtilde "&#x1e7d;">
```

Example usage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd" [
<!ENTITY Vtilde "&#x1e7c;">
<!ENTITY vtilde "&#x1e7d;">
]>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Here is the uppercase V with a tilde char: "&Vtilde;".</p> 
        <p>Here is the lowercase v with a tilde char: "&vtilde;".</p>
    </body>
</html>
```